# unpack in python,I don't know what is wrong

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third, = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

This is the code from "Learn Python the Hard Way", but it doesn't run and I don't know why.

The resulting error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/untitled1/new.py", line 6, in <module>
    script, first, second, third, = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: How many arguments did you pass?

Comment: How did you execute the program?

Comment: i excute the program in Pycharm

Comment: I am a newbie..i am not sure what is " How many arguments did you pass?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Error: "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814128/python-error-valueerror-need-more-than-1-value-to-unpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the arguments you pass to the script when it's run are more than 1. In a terminal, your script would throw the error:

```
$ python ./script.py
```

but this would not

```
$ python ./script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Since you're using PyCharm, you'd need to do the ['Before launch/show this page'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21081281/541208) and edit them there.